# How to assign associative array to collection object in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

Hello Laravel Community,
I am new to Laravel and still learning.

Suppose I query data by using the following code

```
$User = User::where(['UserID' => $request->UserID])->first();
```

and I have an associative array

```
$Data = array(
  ['Username'] => 'Updated Username',
  ['UserEmail'] => 'Updated@gmail.com'
);
```

I wanted to load the associative array to the collection, something like

```
$User->load($Data);
```

I don't want to assign every field one by one, for example

```
$User->Username = $Data['Username'];
$User->UserEmail = $Data['UserEmail'];
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can try with foreach loop.**

$User = User::where(['UserID' => $request->UserID])->first();
foreach($Data as $key => $value){
    $User->$key = $value;    
}
```

For check the value is assign or not then use

```
 dd($User->getAttributes());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Data = array(
  ['Username'] => 'Updated Username',
  ['UserEmail'] => 'Updated@gmail.com'
);


$User = User::where(['UserID' => $request->UserID])->first();
$User->fill($Data);
```